# Modifying layout in resize event

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlayout

*PyQt 5.9.2, Python 3.6.6, Windows 10*

I want to hide/show widgets dynamically depending on current width of their container widget. If `space` takes less than 10% of the whole width button "One" is hidden, then button "Two". When a user makes container larger the buttons are shown again: "Two", then "One".

[image]

Here's a very basic version of my implementation which mostly works, but there's one big problem. I start resizing, button "One" hides, but then some constraint comes into place and the container cannot be reduced in size anymore. I have to release mouse button and start the process again to hide button "Two" too.

[image]

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

form, space, widgets = None, None, None

def resize_event(event):
    if free_space_width() < 0:
        visible_w = [w for w in widgets if w.isVisible()]
        if len(visible_w) > 1:  # do not hide the last one
            for w in visible_w:
                w.hide()
                if free_space_width(w.width()) >= 0:
                    break  # enough space
    else:
        invisible_w = [w for w in widgets if not w.isVisible()]
        for w in reversed(invisible_w):
            if free_space_width(-w.width()) < 0:
                break
            w.show()


def free_space_width(shift=0):
    "Free space should be at least 10% of the bar width"
    return space.width() + shift - 0.1 * form.width()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(form)
    layout.setSpacing(0)  # for simplicity
    form.resize(480, 64)
    form.resizeEvent = resize_event

    widgets = [QtWidgets.QPushButton("test button %d" % (i + 1), form)
               for i in range(3)]
    for i in widgets:
        layout.addWidget(i)
    space = QtWidgets.QWidget(form)  # stretchable space
    s_policy = space.sizePolicy()
    s_policy.setHorizontalStretch(1)
    space.setSizePolicy(s_policy)
    layout.addWidget(space)

    form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: with the code you have provided, I see that it works correctly. That is, if I move the mouse to the left with the mouse pressed without releasing it, the widgets are hidden, first the "1" then the "2" is hidden.

Comment: @eyllanesc for me it works correctly only if resize begins when both buttons are hidden: https://imgur.com/a/MNGcsQW

Comment: In my case PyQt5 5.12.2 in Linux does not generate that problem, could you try the updated version? if it works then the problem would be a bug in the version you use, if not then maybe the problem is a Qt bug but only for your OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> then some constraint comes into place and the container cannot be reduced in size

`layout.setSizeConstraint(QtWidgets.QLayout.SetNoConstraint)`

I think you should implement it under this code like this.

```
layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(form)
layout.setSpacing(0)  # for simplicity
layout.setSizeConstraint(QtWidgets.QLayout.SetNoConstraint)
```

Comment: Thanks, this gave me a clue. Actually my example was not complete because in my project the buttons are inside a container widget which is a subclass of `QFrame`. So I need to reimplement `minimumSizeHint` in my container class and let Qt do everything else.

Answer (score 2):

One can put buttons in a container widget and reimplement `minimumSizeHint` method so Qt does not try to calculate this by itself.

```
def minimumSizeHint(self):
    return QtCore.QSize(150, 30)
```

Update: I've implemented show/hide logic in a [custom layout](https://github.com/Winand/breadcrumbsaddressbar/blob/master/layouts.py)'s `setGeometry` function.

Comment: In my occasion,I had the same problem after executing your code.I solved it by `setSizeConstraint`.Widget came to be moved smoothly without `mouseRelease`.To be honest, my answer was to suggest one solution.It might be in vain.Your answer is useful for my learning, in the rule of SOF,I give you  the second upvode.Thanks.